# How to make json-rpc request with Adonis

Tags: node.js, rpc, bitcoin, adonis.js, requestjs

Am using Adonis to build a Bitcoin RPC system, so am making request with `request.js` Lib, so but the issue is with the callback when I make the request it works but I can't see send the response to the web endpoint, when I console the response from the RPC server it works fine but on postman it is blank.

```
getBlockCount({ response}){
    const dataString = `{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getblockcount","params":[]}`;
    const options = {
        url: `http://${USER}:${PASS}@${HOST}:${PORT}/`,
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        body: dataString
    };
    const returnData;
    const callback = (error, nextRes, body) => {
      if (!error && nextRes.statusCode == 200) {
        const data = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(data)
        returnData = data;
        response.status(200).send(returnData)
      }
      return response.send('data');
    };
    
    return request(options, callback);
    // const options = requestOption(dataString);
    // console.log(rpcRequest(options, callBack(response)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `request-promise`
And this is what it look like

```
async getBlockCount({req, response}){
    return await rp(requestOption(`{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"getblockcount","params":[]}`))
  }

function requestOption(dataString) {
  return {
      url: `http://${USER}:${PASS}@${HOST}:${PORT}/`,
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: dataString
  };
}
```